# Papervision Glitches

Tags: apache-flex, flash

Has anyone seen rendering glitches with Papervision?

Please seee the flash movie at http://www.mapopolis.com/test/ which demonstrates the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Also, you could still use the usual Render Engine, but set the planes on different ViewportLayers. As @Ollie Bourne mentioned, the triangles should sort fine with tesselations/subdivision), those are just some triangles kicking through because the 2 planes are close to each other and have low tesselation. Have a look here for a good guide on this: http://blog.zupko.info/?p=129 . This should be faster than the QuadrantRenderEngine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be fixed easily by using `QuadrantRenderEngine`. But it will consume more cpu than the others.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used papervision much but sometimes shapes distort if they are constructed from a low number of triangles